# yard server generate Documentation from github repo

Tags: ruby, github, chef-infra, yard, yardoc

Is there any way to generate Yard documentation from github projects.
We have several cookbook with Yard tags ready for parsing with Yard and generating documentation.

Any Ideas?

Thanks 
Biswajit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Noah, I found a solution for this. The best example is -http://www.rubydoc.info/. And the github project like is - http://github.com/lsegal/rubydoc.info. This solves my purpose.

Regards
Biswajit

Answer (score 1):

You can run your own instance of `yard server` using the `yard-chef` plugin. You would need to make something to sync the code to the docs server and regenerate the YARD data on changes.